# UIViewController and UIImagePickerController: Unable to create and managing views as expected

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass that contains an instance of UIImagePickerController.  Let's call this controller CameraController.  Among other things, the CameraController manages the UIImagePickerController instance's overlayView, and other views, buttons, labels etc. that are  displayed when the UIImagePickerController, let's call this instance photoPicker, is displayed as the modal controller.

The photoPicker's camera overlay and the elemets that are part of the CameraController view hierarchy display and function as expected.  The problem I'm having is that I cannot use UIViewController's default initializer to create the CameraController's view heirarchy.

I am initializing CameraController from within another UIViewController.  Let's call this controller the WebViewController.  When the user clicks on a button in a view managed by WebViewController, the launchCamera method is called.  It currently looks like this:

```
- (void) launchCamera{ 
    if (!cameraController) {
        cameraController = [[CameraController alloc] init];

//        cameraController = [[CameraController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraController" 
//                                                                  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        cameraController.delegate = self;      
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:cameraController.photoPicker animated:NO];
}
```

I want to be able to create CameraController by calling initWithNibName:bundle: but it's not working
as I'll explain.

CameraController's init method looks like this:

```
- (id) init {
    if (self == [super init]) {

        // Create and configure the image picker here...

        // Load the UI elements for the camera overlay.
        nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CameraController" owner:self options:nil];
        [nibContents retain];

        photoPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

        // More initialization code here...
    }

    return self;
}
```

The only way I can get the elements to load from the CameraController.xib file is to call loadNibNamed:owner:options:. Otherwise the camera takes over but no overlay nor other view components are displayed.  It appears that a side-effect of this problem is that none of the view management methods on CameraController are ever called, like viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear etc.

However, all outlets defined in the nib seem to be working.  For example, when the camera loads a view is displayed with some instructions for the user. On this view is a button to dismiss it. The button is declared in CameraController along with the method that is called that dismisses this instructions view.  It is all wired together through the nib and works great.  Furthermore, the button to take a picture is on the view that servers as photoPicker's overlay.  This button and the method that is called when it's pressed is managed by CameraController and all wired up in the nib.  It works fine too.

So what am I missing?  Why can't I use UIViewController's default initializer to create the CameraController instance.  And, why are none of CameraController's view mangement methods ever called.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does 'overlay' comes from in your code ?

Comment: @Oliver - The overlay is an instance of UIView and is a member of CameraController. It is marked as an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is easy but need some steps.

Well... First, if overlay is an IBOutlet, it can not be loaded at init time. So move picker and co in viewDidLoad. Place also here all other items that your say that they are not loaded. They should be loaded there (viewDIDLoad). Check that outlets are connected.

Second, call

```
cameraController = [[CameraController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraController" 
                                                                 bundle:nil];
```

and ensure that CameraController contains (just) a view, and CameraController inherits UIViewController. Check also file's owner.

And at some time, you may consider that calling :

```
[self presentModalViewController:cameraController.photoPicker animated:NO];
```

does not make the CameraController control your picker. Does that make sense to you ?

What does that do regarding your problem ?

It seems you are confusing some things. I try to explain in another way :

The one that controls the picker is the one that is its delegate. Your may consider creating in a MAIN view.
The controller of the overlay (added as subview) is the one that own its view in File's Owner. That may be created from the MAIN view, adding its view as subview of the controller.  Basically, it is loaded just to get the overlay, but viewDidLoad, ... won't be called.
That's all and I belive those steps are not ok in your code.
That should give something like :

MainController

```
Loadcamera {
   self.picker = [UIImagePicker alloc] init.....];
   self.picker.delegate = self;

   SecondController* scnd = [[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:nil];
   [self.picker addOverlay:scnd.view];

   [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
}

/// And here manage your picker delegate methods
```

SecondController

```
// Here manage your IBActions and whatever you want for the overlay
```